# Python IDLE can't be opened by double-clicking .py files in Finder

Tags: macos, terminal, finder, python

I can't open `.py` files in IDLE by double-clicking them in Finder (IDLE is currently set as the default program for opening such files).  Nor can I open those files by right-clicking and selecting IDLE.

If IDLE is already open I can open `.py` files through the `File > Open` method.  Once IDLE is open I can also just double-click `.py` files and they will open in IDLE.  Finally, in the Terminal, I can open `.py` files just fine by typing `idle -e file.py` even if IDLE has not yet been opened.

I just can't open IDLE itself by double-clicking on `.py` files, or by right-clicking on `.py` files and selecting IDLE.

I'm using OSX 10.8.2 and Python/IDLE 2.7.3.  Anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: `env PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin idle file.py` works for me, I can't check your version since I have not installed Tkinter for my Python3.3 I use. Have you installed other python than default?

Comment: @EirNym, I had Python 2.7.3 and Python 2.6 (from python.org) installed on my machine, and then I uninstalled both and re-installed OSX and XCode.  Then I reinstalled Python 2.7.3 (again from python.org).  In which file are you setting the path in your comment?

Comment: As IDLE is a GUI it won't look at any change in your path in .profile files - does the Apple IDLE work?

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on a python file and select get info. Near the bottom of the get info window is a section that reads Open With. You can select a version of Idle to use. There is a button below that reads change all. If you click this, then all files with .py extension will be opened with idle. Just tested this and it works.  Below is an image indicating the relevant points.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to install python 2.7.3 on ML since it's default.
2. If you really need custom installation of python (if you need special site packages for example), you need to install it from mac ports or from home brew (I do prefer mac ports). And rule custom packages from that location.
3. To make IDLE runnable from your python installation you have to resolve all dependencies such as TKinter.

Package systems such as Brew and MacPorts and others often split Python base to `python` core, `python-tk` and `python-sqlite3` depending on the package manager and maintainer opinion. Package name may vary and easily searchable.

Comment: I'm really confused.  When I installed ML, the default version of Python I got (when I typed "python" at the command line) was 2.7.2, not 2.7.3.  Also I wasn't aware that IDLE came pre-installed on ML.  Based on your answer, I'm no longer sure how to tell the ML pre-installed Python/IDLE versions from the python.org ones.

Comment: You can freely to remove python from python.org and install from MacPorts if you need different python to setup site packages

Comment: You can install python 2.7.16 and python3 directly from python.org as an installer .pkg, without having to use HomeBrew or Mac Ports. Those installers include IDLE.

Comment: Thank you! `brew install python-tk` worked for me.

Comment: @EirNym can you provide links to your last statement - Macports does not do this split does Homebrew?

Comment: @mmmmmm agree for MacPorts, many others do, like FreeBSD ports, various distributions of linux.

Comment: @EirNym Thjis site is for Apple products so only macos matters here what happens on Linux or FreeBSD is just a confusion and in this question it really does not help

Comment: true, I added them to a comment, as it's a common practice and it's worth a while to check this python package just in case. There's also NixPkgs which are macOS related. it surprisingly ships sqlite package but not sqlite3 as a dependency. So It's worth a while check both these two packages if they're "fully installed" to be used.